# String become nil after viewDidLoad with protocol and delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols

I have a protocol and delegate and I have it send a string then change the Tab on a UItabbar, My protocol and delegate works just find and it sets a string in the viewcontroller but as soon as the view finishes loading it becomes nil
Here is my code;

```
-(void)duplicateAsset:(NSString *)serialNumber{

    [self setDubString:serialNumber];
    NSLog(@"delegate called DubString = %@",self.dubString);

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"_dubString in viewDidLoad = %@",self.dubString);
}
```

Output

```
 delegate called DubString = SERIALNUMBER
 _dubString in viewDidLoad = (null)
```

I'm not sure whats going on because I have done this many times before.

EDIT:
I updated what the log says. I have set the string properties to `copy` and to `strong` and I still can't get the string to stay

Comment: You code appears to be wrong: having %@ in the format string in NSLog call you need to provide an argument to place the value of there, like NSLog(@"Dub string %@", dubString)

Comment: this line NSLog(@"Dub String In View Load = %@"); should be NSLog(@"Dub String In View Load = %@", dubString); only then you can check if its nil or not!

Comment: Are you sure you are properly NSLog-ing ? Your code states : NSLog(@"Dub String In View Load = %@"); Instead of : NSLog(@"Dub String In View Load = %@", self.dubString);

Comment: wops! so many people giving the same answer :)

Comment: Looks like the data on stack played badly with you, leading to errorneous print of the string you wanted to check in the first call. It didn't play the same trick on the second method as the stack got rewritten a bunch times, and it led you to a wrong conclusion :)

Comment: Sorry the %@ is wrong I was just typing this because I was a away from my computer but in my code its right.

Comment: It's like that in my code I was just typing it from memory and I forgot to add that in my question.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the code shown you do not actually give `dubString` as argument to `NSLog`, is this the actual code you're using? If yes, then that's the problem, add `, self.dubString` before the closing `)` of `NSLog`. If not, then check that the `dubString` property is set to `strong` or `copy` (or, if it's not a property, that your `setDubString:` method takes ownership of the string or copy thereof).

**edit**: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code shown, so if you are unable to trace the bug, post more code (e.g., all contexts where dubString is set, such as the place where you are calling `duplicateAsset`).

Meanwhile I would suggest checking that you are calling `duplicateAsset` on the same object that has its `viewDidLoad` called (include the object id of `self` in both debug printouts). Also ensure that nothing else sets `dubString` in between, e.g., define the `setDubString:` accessor yourself and add a debug printout (or breakpoint) there.